# How to remove 2 characters from the beginning of a string after using filename-modifiers?

Tags: command-line, string-manipulation

How to remove 2 characters from the beginning of a string after using filename-modifiers?
So assume that I have a files that looks like this:

```
/home/drskoolie/projects/examples/ex40.c

/home/drskoolie/projects/examples/ex1.c
```

What I want is to get the number 40 and 1 out of the file names respectively using filename-modifiers (this is later going to a function that will send it to another tmux window). Writing this command gets me almost there: `:!echo '%:p:t:r'`

```
ex40

ex1
```

How do I now remove the first two characters here to get:

```
40 

1
```

Comment: You can't use filename modifiers for this; you can use something like `trim('ex')` or `matchstr('\d\+')` to get the number. If you want it to work in the shell context with `:!` you'll have to use something like `| grep -o '\d+'`.

Answer (score 1):

Any of the following would work with your specific examples:

```
:echo expand('%:p:t:r')->matchstr('\d\+$')
:echo expand('%:p:t:r')->trim('ex', 1) " the third direction argument might be new?
:echo expand('%:p:t:r')[2:]
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the best solution, but should work :)

### Command

`!echo $(var=%< && echo ${var/ex/})`

### Explanation

1. starts subshell and asigns `%<` to `var` (%< means current file without extenction)
2. echo the variable `var` with a **command substitution**, 'ex' -> ' '

**In short:** Echo current filename without extenction and replace 'ex' with nothing.

###### Endword

Hope this helped you :)